# What is a logarithmic divergence?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, singularities, regularization

I am reading about renormalisation in QED and I come across the term logarithmic divergence several times. Can somebody explain to me about it in simple terms?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The term 'logarithmic divergence' is normally used for integrals of the type
$$
F(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{1}{\xi}\mathrm d\xi
$$
(or possibly of the form $F(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{1}{\xi}f(\xi)\mathrm d\xi$ where $f(\xi)$ approaches some finite limit when $\xi\to\infty$). In these cases, the integral diverges to infinity when $x\to\infty$, but it does this relatively slowly: in fact, as a logarithm, since
$$
F(x) \approx \log(x)
$$
for the finite cas (or $F(x)\approx F_0 \log(x)+\mathrm{regular}(x)$ if a non-constant $f$ is introduced).

Comment: The case $x_0 \to \infty$ would also be a logarithmic divergence, no?

Comment: @gj255 Yes, obviously, as is the case $x_0\to 0$.